# How to remove "deprecation" in Atom IDE?

Tags: ide, atom-editor

Does anyone know how to remove the annoying **"deprecations"** word in the right bottom corner from Atom IDE?.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: The "deprecation" in the bottom corner means that you are using at least two items in your code that are deprecated. To remove them, find the deprecations and remove them or suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily remove it. File => Settings => Packages => Core Packages => Deprecation Cop => Disable

Answer (score 2):

I've seen where the deprecated call is part of Atom itself:

[image: Deprecated calls atom core]

It could also be due to an incompatible package but troubleshooting those becomes an endless chore. [Thankfully it's possible to edit the css](https://discuss.atom.io/t/deprecation-warnings/15021/9):

`Atom->Stylesheet... (styles.less)`

Before:

[image]

I found that changing the text color from orange to default was enough for me:

```
.deprecation-cop-status {
  color: inherit;
}
```

[image]

You can also hide it completely (use `visibility: hidden;` to preserve width if desired):

```
.deprecation-cop-status {
   display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent ! Havnt found any other solution to the core atom deprecation warning dating from April 2021 indeed

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the deprecation word, and it should open a new tab telling you what's wrong. Update or delete the package that causes the deprecations and the word will be removed.